# What is the quantum Hall resistance R_H as a function of magnetic field?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

For the integer quantum Hall effect, the resistance $R_H = h/(ne^2)$, where $n$ is some integer. All of the graphs of $R_H$ as a function of magnetic field, $B$, that I've seen show that at $B = 0$, $n = \infty$, and as $B$ increases, $n$ decreases in steps until it reaches 1.

How do you determine the value of $n$ as a function of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependence comes through the magnetic flux, $\Phi$, through the sample. The number of states per Landau level is proportional to $\frac{\Phi}{\Phi_0}$, where $\Phi_0=\frac{hc}e$ is the fundamental quantum of flux. For a given sample, the total number of charge carriers if fixed. Thus, as $B$ and hence $\Phi$ increase, the number of filled Landau levels decreases. The positive integer $n$ denotes the number of filled Landau levels in your formula. See [the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization) for some details. You need to know the density of charge carriers to get an explicit formula that relates $n$ directly to $B$.